# Set wrong value of relative path in form component in Linux in install4j

Tags: installation, install4j

When I am setting relative path in **File Chooser** form component in Linux environment using install4j installer it sets wrong value like I read data/conf/truststore.txt relative path from properties file and then set this path to **File Chooser** form component, instead of setting path "data/conf/truststore.txt" it sets "ES210/configure.sh.15633.dir/data/conf/truststore.txt". How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the relative file is relative to the working directory. To set it relative to the installation directory, set it to

```
${installer:sys.installationDir}/data/conf/truststore.txt
```